# How to increase touchpad drag lock delay?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, drag-and-drop, libinput

First off, by "drag lock" I mean that, whatever is being dragged with a normal touchpad drag, isn't released when the finger is lifted off the touchpad. Hence, having reached the edge of the touchpad, one can reposition the finger away from the edge to continue dragging further. This typically has some delay after which the drag is released. How can this delay be controlled?

I just got a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it. In Ubuntu 16.04 I had somehow managed to get touchpad drag lock working with `synclient LockedDrags=1`. Now `synclient` however gives me

> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

I tried installing synaptic(s) and libsynaptic(s) but couldn't get it working. I tried also to figure out how to achieve drag lock with libinput but couldn't. Finally I stumbled across this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag-lock true
```

This achieves almost what I want (although I don't know yet if its effect will persist after logging out and in, or after rebooting). The only remaining thing is to increase the really short release delay, but I couldn't figure out how to control it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: As per Rinzwind's suggestion, I tried the following commands and got the following output:

```
pete@probook:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
[sudo] password for pete: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version (1.9.1-1ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
pete@probook:~$ synclient -l | grep -i drag
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
pete@probook:~$
```

I had also earlier copied the former to the latter:

```
pete@probook:~$ ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf 
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
pete@probook:~$ ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf 
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
pete@probook:~$
```

Comment: do you have `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`? `synclient` is part of that. if not try and install that and then do `synclient -l | grep -i drag` it then should show the option and `synclient LockedDragTimeout={n}` will work with {n} set to a digit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Rinzwind, I edited accordingly. It looks like I have ```xserver-xorg-input-synaptics``` but ```synclient``` properties can't be found. I have seen and tried googling about that error message before, but haven't understood how to fix things.

Comment: do you have `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf`? If 1 = yes and 2 = no copy the 1st into  to the 2nd and try again (after a reboot)

Comment: I had done that already earlier; see the edits.